# compile order eclipse c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, compilation, include

I am trying Unit test using Gtest.

I am creating a another project that has file from the original project (By linking) that is to be tested. In the new project I then create Fake Implementation and Mocks of the additional dependencies of the function or Unit I want to test. In the file from the original project I am using #ifdef to include original dependencies or the fake implementation

The problem I am facing is I need to compile the files in particular order so that the fake implementations are included when test project is build. 
I am using MCUXpresso on Windows 10 with MinGW, GNU Builder

Anticipating any workaround or way to get control over order in which files are compiled.

```
#ifdef IsTesting        //This is part or original project, original header files
#include "Fake_dependency"
#else
#include "Original_Dependency"
#endif
```

Then in the new project I define

```
#define IsTesting true // Part of Test_Project, followed by other code for testing
```

when I compile the new project or test project I need this file having this variable defined to be compiled first or earlier than the file that I am linking from the Original project

Comment: Compile order of cpp files doesn't matter. Maybe you mean the link order?

Comment: Compilation order doesn't matter in C++. You maybe need to include the right header files in your C++ file...

Comment: I don't really understand why order is relevant to your situation but if you do need to compile in a specific order then you can build your own `Makefile`.

Comment: I get compile error as it tries to include header files that are not present in the New project. It happens as compiler dont know that the variable is defined as it compiles in order that I dont have any control on.

Comment: Somehow writing own Makefile is not possible and/or allowed. MCUXpresso generates its own Makefile and overwrite then in every build so editing them is also not working

Comment: That line defining `IsTesting` probably just needs to be `#included` in the relevant header files. Maybe put it in a special project header that everything includes? Or, if you have access to the compile command, set it by the compiler flag `-DIsTesting=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining `IsTesting` in your test code, you can add the definition to your Build Configuration for the test project.

Go to Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Select the appropriate language (GNU C++) and add "IsTesting" (without any value)

If you want Eclipse to get the compiled code right (not compiled code is gray) you will have to toggle 
Properties -> C/C++ General -> Indexer -> Use active build configuration as well

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It has triggered my curiosity though.. How does the compiler know about the variable defined in the project settings?

Comment: Eclipse uses the project settings to handle the automatized build. For me that means eclipse changes the generated build command. But i guess that depends on what kind of build system you use. in the end it is the *build configuration* we are talking about